# Не могу получить изображение через Curl

Tags: php, curl

Пытаюсь получить изображение через Curl - получаю false, file_get_contents - false

```
$headers = array (
      'Host: www.encartemix.com.br',
      'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
      'Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
      'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
      'Connection: keep-alive',
      'Pragma: no-cache',
      'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
      'Cache-Control: no-cache',
      'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'
    );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.encartemix.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/GUARA08-1-950x1344.jpg');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$image = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

есть идеи?

Comment: У меня все работает, ваш код. На каком моменте у вас не так все идет?

Comment: @Mully на этом моменте и сыпется все. без проблем получаю страницу, на которой собираю ссылки на изображение. но пытаюсь получить изображение - и false

Comment: Попробуйте открыть картинку в браузере, она у вас открывается?

Comment: @Mully с этим все четко. только что решилась проблема. оказывается имеет значение (вот самое последнее о чем подумалось) заголовок юзерагента. ппц! а именно в этом заголовке - выиграла версия хрома (Chrome/52.0.2743.116) против (Chrome/71.0.3578.80)

Comment: Супер)) я только отправлял с теми же заголовками что и у вас, у пеня результат пришёл))))

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в самое начало вашего скрипта:

```php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Comment: спасибо, но не решает проблему